# What is the difference between git checkout -b <name> and git branch <name>

Tags: git

I can create develop branch by `git branch <branchname>`, and I also can create dev branch by git `checkout -b <branchname>`. Is the effect of the two command exactly the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git branch <branchname>` creates a new branch.

`git checkout -b <branchname>` creates a new branch and checks out the newly created branch.